# Using CString to Convert int and Send to Console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, console-application, cstring

My console application attempts to write an integer to the console:

```
int i = 170;
CString cs;
cs.Format( L"%d", i );
wcout << cs << endl;
```

I expect "`170`" to be written to the console, but what happens is "`00E21280`".  This is the *address*.  I have verified that "170" is saved at that memory location.  Any ideas?

Comment: Something wrong with std::string?

Comment: @DeadMG:  Jim Fell must be a fan of buggy, hacky, ancient & non-portable technology,.

Comment: @DeadMG, I don't think you could use std::string for this unless you were also using Boost Format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast it to a string, otherwise it treats it as a pointer.

```
wcout << (PCTSTR)cs << endl;
```

Comment: I think it should be wcout << (LPCTSTR)cs << endl; but I don't have enough rep to edit your post. +1 to you anyway though.

Comment: LPCTSTR is an aged usage, of some use when we transitioned from Win16. There's no need nowadays for the "L" prefixed appendix :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
wcout << (LPCTSTR)cs << endl;
```